# Analytic continuation of $y=\sqrt{x^4-x^2+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, analytic-functions

**Question.** Consider the function $y=\sqrt{x^4-x^2+1}$. Consider a sufficiently large
circle $C$ of $0$ in $\mathbb{C}$, and let $x_0$ lies in this circle (suppose
$x$ is not a branch point of this function). We choose
a solution $y_0$ for $x_0$. How would one show that by analytically continueing
$(x_0,y_0)$ along this circle, when one returns to $x_0$, the corresponding solution
is still $y_0$, rather than $-y_0$?

**Side note.**
In other words, consider the double covering
$\varphi:\{(x,y): y^2=x^4-x^2+1\}\to 
\mathbb{C}$ by projecting to $x$. For sufficiently large $R$, $U_R:=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|>R\}$,
the above question is the same as asking that
$\varphi^{-1}(U_R)$ is not path-connected.

Or equivalently, from $y^2=x^2-x^2+1$, we get a double covering map
$X\to \mathbb{P}^1$ where $X$ is a compact Riemann surface. The above
question is equivalently to asking to show that $\infty$ is unramified.

**An attempt.** I learned this from [page 13](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eamathew/287y.pdf), but I am not completely convinced
by this informal approach: As $x$ goes around the circle and get back, its argument
increases by $2\pi$, so the arguments of $x^4$ and $x^2$ increase by $8\pi$
and $4\pi$, respectively. It means the argument of $x^4-x^2$ increases
by $8\pi-4\pi=4\pi$, meaning $x^4-x^2+1$ has argument increases by $4\pi$
(with respect to center $1$), so $y^2$ has argument increases by $4\pi$ around $1$
(I don't think this makes sense?), so $y$ has argument increases by $2\pi$.
This means we cannot reach $-y$ by analytically continuing along this circle.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The paragraph about your attempt has some inaccuracies. The argument of $x^4$ does increase by $8\pi$. But $x^2-1$ is much smaller than $x^4$ for a large enough circle $C$. Therefore, the argument of $(x^4-(x^2-1))$ just increases by $8\pi$.

Comment: Thanks! But I guess you mean the argument increases "approximately" by $8\pi$, as we still need to take $x^2-1$ into account?

Comment: There is a sense in which the argument literally increases by $8\pi$, provided that the circle is large enough. Think about $g(e^{2\pi it})$, with $t$ ranging from 0 to 1. Try to represent the **argument** of $g(e^{2\pi it})$, as a function $f$ from [0,1] to $\mathbb{R}$. There is a unique way to do this modulo your choice of $f(0)$. And it is always the case that $f(1)-f(0)=8\pi$. If you have not seen this idea before, you might want to look up winding numbers or the fundamental group of the circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link, in case you don't know what it means for two paths to be homotopic:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(topology)#:~:text=Homotopy%20of%20paths,-Main%20article%3A%20Homotopy&text=Paths%20and%20loops%20are%20central,while%20keeping%20its%20endpoints%20fixed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(topology)#:%7E:text=Homotopy%20of%20paths,-Main%20article%3A%20Homotopy&text=Paths%20and%20loops%20are%20central,while%20keeping%20its%20endpoints%20fixed).

Let $g(z)=z^4-z^2+1$.

The idea of the "informal approach" is that the path $g(Re^{2\pi it})$, where $t$ ranges from $0$ to $1$, is homotopic to the path $g(R)e^{8\pi it}$, that is to say the path that starts at $g(R)$ and goes round the circle clockwise **four times** at a fixed rate.

That will indeed allow you to construct a continuous square root of $g(z)$, at least for $z$ on the circle $C$.

$\\$

There is another, even simpler approach. For the sake of generality, I'll talk about finding the square root of $h(z)=p(z)$, where $p(z)$ is a polynomial and $\deg{p(z)}=2n$.

Think about $u(z)=z^{2n}h(1/z)$. For a small enough $r$, the square root of $u(z)$ is analytic on $|z|<r$. Call this square root $w(z)$.

Clearly $z^{-n}w(z)$ is a square root of $h(1/z)$ that is analytic on $0<|z|<r$.

So $z^{n}w(1/z)$ is a square root of $h(z)$ that is analytic on $|z|>1/r$.

Comment: I am not sure I follow your argument. The path I do analytic continuation is $\gamma(t)=Re^{2\pi i t}$, instead of $g(Re^{2\pi it})$ or $g(R) e^{8\pi i t}$. I know that analytic continuation along homotopic paths give the same function, but I don't see how to use it along your lines? Also, I don't understand how $z^{-n}w(z)$ can be analytic on $|z|<r$? For example, $p(z)=z^2$ then $z^{-1} \sqrt{1+z^2}$ is not analytic at $0$?

Comment: As for the second approach, my apologies, it is not analytic at 0, but it is analytic on the punctured disc, which suffices for the argument. I have edited my answer.

Comment: As for the first approach: to put it in a crude way, if you can square-root the latter path (and you obviously can), you can square-root the former path. Do you see how to formalise and prove this?

Comment: To square-root a path $b(t)$ is to find a path $a(t)$ such that $(a(t))^2=b(t)$

Comment: I think I see what you mean: We can analytically continued the square-root function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ along path $g(R) e^{8\pi it}$. Since $g(R) e^{8\pi it}$ and $g(Re^{2\pi i t})$ are homotopic, it implies that $\sqrt{x}$ can also be analytically continued along $g(Re^{2\pi i t})$, which gives the same function as in the case of $g(R) e^{8\pi it}$. Thanks for this!

Comment: For your second approach, a few more question if you don't mind. Why do you need to put $+1$ in $h(z)=1+p(z)$. Isn't it enough to assume $h(z)$ to be any even-degree polynomial?

Comment: indeed the "1+" is a mistake, I'll edit it

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach.  Expand $\sqrt{x^4-x^2+1}$ near $x=\infty$:
$$
\sqrt{x^4-x^2+1} = x^2\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}}
$$
So if we choose the branch of $\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}}$ that is $1$ when $x=\infty$, we get a Laurent series:
$$
\sqrt{x^4-x^2+1} = x^2 - \frac{1}{2} +\frac{3}{8} x^{-2} + \frac{3}{16} x^{-4} + \dots
$$
This series has no fractional powers, so it is analytic in a punctured neighborhood of $\infty$.